# deploy Laravel in kubernetes

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a laravel application in kubernetes at Google Cloud Platform.

I followed couple of tutorials and was successful trying them locally on a docker VM.

https://learnk8s.io/blog/kubernetes-deploy-laravel-the-easy-way

https://blog.cloud66.com/deploying-your-laravel-php-applications-with-cloud-66/

But when tried to deploy in kubernetes using an ingress to assign a domain name to the application. I keep getting the 502 bad gateway page.

I'm using a nginx ingress controller with image k8s.gcr.io/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3 and my ingress is as following

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domainname.com
    secretName: sslcertificate
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

this is my application service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
  labels:
    name: demo
    version: v1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: demo
  type: NodePort
```

this is my ingress controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  labels:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        # Any image is permissable as long as:
        # 1. It serves a 404 page at /
        # 2. It serves 200 on a /healthz endpoint
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        # use downward API
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        # we expose 18080 to access nginx stats in url /nginx-status
        # this is optional
        - containerPort: 18080
          hostPort: 18080
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
```

and here is my laravel application deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-rc
  labels:
    name: demo
    version: v1
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: demo
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/projectname/laravelapp:vx
        name: app-pod
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

I tried to add the domain entry to the hosts file but with no luck !!
is there a specific configurations I have to add to the configmap.yaml file for the nginx ingress controller?

Comment: `serviceName: service` can you show us your service manifest? (The YAML document with `kind: Ingress` )

Comment: I edited the post with all the yaml files

Comment: Why is service `type: NodePort` and can you show us the Deployment/ReplicaSet/DaemonSet/Pod manifest?

Comment: I edit the post and i added the deployment from the laravel application. Always use type: NodePort for the service when assigning a kubernetes ingress and works for me all the time

Comment: Since the entrypoint for the laravel application is in the `public/` directory, wouldn't you need to rewrite your `ingress.yaml` to match this?

Comment: tried that already but didn't work

Comment: Are you able to have a look at the nginx error logs? I think they'd give you a good idea of what is going on.

Comment: I checked it and found this error => [error] 127#127: *866 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.231.110.74, server: singapore.smartlabplatform.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.12.1.39:8080/", host: "singapore.smartlabplatform.com <= that's why i asked if there is a specific configmap i need to deploy

Answer (score 1):

In short, to be able to reach your application via external domain name (singapore.smartlabplatform.com), you need to create a A DNS record for GCP L4 Load Balancer's external IP address (this is in other words EXTERNAL-IP of your default nginx-ingress-controller's Service), here seen as pending:

```
==> v1/Service
NAME                            TYPE          CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer  10.7.248.226  pending      
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP     10.7.245.75   none
```

how to do this? it's explained on the GKE tutorials page [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip).

In the current state of your environment you can only reach your application in two ways:

1. From outside, via Load Balancer EXTERNAL-IP:

   [image]
2. From inside, your Kubernetes cluster using **laravel-kubernetes-demo** service dns name:

> $ curl  laravel-kubernetes-demo.default.svc.cluster.local
>
> ```
> <title>Laravel Kubernetes Demo :: LearnK8s</title>
> ```

If you want all that magic, like the automatic creation of DNS records, happen along with appearance of `host: domain.com` in your ingress resource spec, you should use [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) (makes Kubernetes resources discoverable via public DNS servers), and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/gke.md) is the tutorial on how to set it up specifically for GKE.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning but I laready use cloudflare to manage the dns records and I already updated the ingress's IP address in there.

Comment: In my opinion your issue might have to do with the fact, you are using very outdated version of ingress-controller, probably even alpha version (nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3 ). I successfully tested your scenario with nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0.

Comment: I tested with the nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0 but still not working for me..did you test yours with a PHP application?did you have to use a customized configmap ? if yes can you share it with me. Also I learned that it's not possible to use nginx INGRESS CONTROLLER with PHP application because it doesn't' support any fastcgi config options hence the upstream error i keep getting and rather use a nginx SERVER hosted in the same pod as the PHP application or have a sperate deployment for it.

Comment: You mentioned in the description of your issue, that you are following couple of 
 tutorials linked above, which in fact are using apache-php based container images, that`s true. Investigating your issue in context of manual modifications done by you to the original source code is out of scope of this post (please create a new post or update this one with all details). From a quick google search I can see there exist variants of PHP server specific extensions working with NGINX.  For instance PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is an alternative PHP FastCGI, search for: PHP-FPM docker image.